# What is the best way to check whether Durable Functions failed in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

When I called Web Activity after Azure Functions Activity (Durable Functions) in a pipeline, Web Activity's Status became 'Succeeded' even if Durable Functions' output.statusQueryGetUri-runtimeStatus is 'Failed'.

What is the best way to check whether Durable Functions failed in Azure Data Factory ?

I currently configure an 'If Condition' Activity after Web Activity.

The 'If Condition' Activity's properties are here:

- Expression: `@equals(activity('<Web Activity's name>').output.runtimeStatus, 'Completed')`
- True: No activities
- False: 1 Activity

  - Fail Activity

Is there a better way to check whether Durable Functions failed?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to check the Durable Functions failure in azure data factory and the one which you are searching is the best way to find out durable functions failure.

- First, we trigger our Durable Function through an HTTP trigger using Azure Function activity.
- Then with the Until activity, we check status of that function.

  - The Wait activity waits around 30 seconds (or different, up to you) to let function to be executed.
  - The Web activity makes a request to the statusQueryUrl that Azure Function activity returns, by calling  `@activity('StartUntar').output.statusQueryGetUri`
- Until activity checks the result of CheckStatus Web activity with expression  `@not(or(equals(activity('CheckStatus').output.runtimeStatus, 'Pending'), equals(activity('CheckStatus').output.runtimeStatus, 'Running')))`
- It repeats until the function is finished or failed, or until it times out (set on the Timeout property)

Here is the [Azure Data Factory Document](https://www.harunlegoz.com/2019/06/19/azure-data-factory-durable-functions/) for complete information about Durable Functions failure.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I read [another page](https://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/12/using-azure-durable-functions-with.html). The author of this blog also refered the page which you suggested in [the earlier page](http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/10/using-durable-functions-in-azure-data.html). In the newer page, he wrote `In reality, the combination of Until loop container along with Wait and Web call activities can just be replaced by a single Web call activity.`. So I think that we do not need Until Activity.